# map/set iterator no dereferencable for seemingly no reason

Tags: c++, iterator, maps, dereference

I wrote this program which checks if words given in  a list are anagrams of each other, and for some reason my program seems to only get about halfway through running until I get a runtime error that says "map/set iterator not dereferencable". Ive been staring at this for a while now and trying to debug it and I can't figure out the problem, so I was hoping someone here could? Below is the code:

```
// Anagrams.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream ifs("words.txt");// opens file
    if (!ifs) {
        cout << "no file";
        exit(1);
    }

    set<string>anagrams;
    map<string, string>words;
    string word;
    while (ifs >> word) {
        string sortedWord = word;
        sort(sortedWord.begin(), sortedWord.end());
        words.insert(pair<string, string>(word, sortedWord));
    }

    for (map<string, string>::iterator i = words.begin(); i != words.end(); i++) {
        //cout << "test i for loop" << endl;
        for (map<string, string>::iterator j = words.begin(); j != words.end(); j++) {
            //cout << "test j for loop" << endl;
            if (i->first == j->first) {
                j++;
            }
            if (i->second == j->second) {
                anagrams.insert(i->first);
                anagrams.insert(j->first);
                for (set<string>::iterator i = anagrams.begin(); i != anagrams.end(); i++) {
                    cout << *i << " ";
                }
                cout << endl;
                anagrams.clear();
                //cout << i->first << " is an anagram of " << j->first << " and their sorted version is " << i->second << endl;

            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And below is the word list:

```
monday
dynamo
abbot
acne
alert
alter
baby
Baby
BABY
best
bets
cane
later
Unix
UNIX
```

and the output is this before I get the runtime pop-up error:

```
acne cane
alert alter
alert later
alert alter
alert later
best bets
best bets
acne cane
dynamo monday
alert later
alert later
dynamo monday
```

then the error.

(Excuse the crappy output, I can fix that later. More concerned with the error at the moment)

Thanks

Comment: It's because you say `j++` without checking whether `j` is already `end()`.

Comment: So whats the syntax for that using iterators? `j!=words.end()-1;` isn't working

Comment: Rethink the algorithm? Maybe replace `j++` by `continue`?